# How to send SMS to mobile using C# code?

Tags: c#, wpf, sms

I need sample code or any free gateways to send SMS to mobile using C# code, I search lot of examples but I didn't find any sample for my requirement, how can I do for using free SMS services.

Thanks,
@praveen

Comment: Just think about it: why would anyone offer a free SMS gateway? The clickatell recommendation is sensible though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know any free services - but - this one is rather cheap, it's 10$ for 100 messages per month (to EU). They have API that is extreamly easy to use and will even give you sandbox account with 5 credits to spare.

I couldn't be more satisfied with them.

try http://www.message-media.com/

best regards,
P.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any free SMS gateways. If you decide to pay for one I would recommend the http://www.clickatell.com/ SMS gateway.